# Tutorial 4 of SharePoint SPFx Tutorials Azure Instructions Unclear

Tags: spfx-tooling, spfx-webparts

The Instructions in Tutorial 4 of the SharePoint SPFx Tutorials are unclear in terms of what is required from Azure.

Instructions for creating Storage account name, Blob Container Name and Storage Account Access Key are not clear. They just point to a generic set of instructions. eg Blob Container Name - what sort of access type to the BLOB Container is required ? Private, Container or BLOB ?

Also Path to CDN - No instructions for finding this - is this a url ? if so what sort of url ? - an example would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the [tutorial](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/HelloWorld,-Deploy-to-CDN) to now include detailed steps. Please let us know if that works. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Chakkardeep - they were fine. I was able to follow the instruction, deploy the client side web part and it worked.